# Keep on getting same error after cargo checking the code

Tags: substrate-node-template

Code:

```rs
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
    use sp_std::vec::Vec;

    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
    }
    

    

    #[pallet::event]   
    #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
    pub enum Event<T: Config> {
        ClaimCreated(T::AccountId, Vec<u8>),
        ClaimRevoked(T::AccountId, Vec<u8>),
    }

    #[pallet::error]   
    pub enum Error<T> {
        ProofAlreadyClaimed,
        NoSuchProof,
        NotProofOwner,
    }

    #[pallet::pallet]
    #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

    #[pallet::storage] // <-- Step 5. code block will replace this.
    pub(super) type Proofs<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, Vec<u8>, (T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber), ValueQuery>;

    #[pallet::hooks]
    impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {}

    #[pallet::call]   // <-- Step 6. code block will replace this.
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::weight(1_000)]
        pub fn create_claim(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            proof: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            // Check that the extrinsic was signed and get the signer.
            // This function will return an error if the extrinsic is not signed.
            // https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/origins
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            // Verify that the specified proof has not already been claimed.
            ensure!(!Proofs::<T>::contains_key(&proof), Error::<T>::ProofAlreadyClaimed);

            // Get the block number from the FRAME System module.
            let current_block = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();

            // Store the proof with the sender and block number.
            Proofs::<T>::insert(&proof, (&sender, current_block));

            // Emit an event that the claim was created.
            Self::deposit_event(Event::ClaimCreated(sender, proof));

            Ok(())
        }

        #[pallet::weight(10_000)]
        pub fn revoke_claim(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            proof: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            ensure!(Proofs::<T>::contains_key(&proof), Error::<T>::NoSuchProof);

            let (owner, _) = Proofs::<T>::get(&proof);

            ensure!(sender == owner, Error::<T>::NotProofOwner);

            Proofs::<T>::remove(&proof);

            Self::deposit_event(Event::ClaimRevoked(sender, proof));

            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

```rs
Error:
error: Invalid usage of RuntimeEvent, Config contains no associated type RuntimeEvent, but enum Event is declared (in use of #[pallet::event]). An RuntimeEvent associated type must be declare on trait Config.

    |
  4 | #[frame_support::pallet]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro frame_support::pallet (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error: could not compile pallet-template (lib) due to previous error
```

Answer (score 1):

The name is hardcoded.

Refer to https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/41ad4a6c9d712ac4b6e16e79a8b3837af8234f46/pallets/template/src/lib.rs#L32.

Replace `Event` with `RuntimeEvent`.